# Python BeautifulSoup - ignore child tags and IDs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a file that has the below structure.

I want to find all the parent tags, i.e. all the IDs that contain numbers only, and the text contained within. However, now I get a flat structure of all `a` tags, both parents and children tags.

```
<A ID=101>
<a id=”A1”>Today is a nice day. 
<a id=”A2”>Today is a very nice day.
<a id=”A3”>Today is a very very nice day.
</A>

<A ID=102>
<a id=”A1”>Today is a nice day2. 
<a id=”A2”>Today is a very nice day2.
<a id=”A3”>Today is a very very nice day2.
</A>
```

I want this only and ignore all child tags and IDs. What is a way to extract it like this?

```
<A ID=101>
Today is a nice day. 
Today is a very nice day.
Today is a very very nice day.
</A>

<A ID=102>
Today is a nice day2. 
Today is a very nice day2.
Today is a very very nice day2.
</A>
```

Comment: Where is your code?  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you sure the HTML is exactly like this? If you put this on `bs` it gives a weird output.

Comment: @ipinak yes that is correct. It's not an HTML file, it's a text file in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code could do what you are asking for provided the child and parent tags have different names and are not just uppercase and lower case versions of each other

```
html = """
<B ID=101>
<a id=”A1”>Today is a nice day. 
<a id=”A2”>Today is a very nice day.
<a id=”A3”>Today is a very very nice day.
</B>

<B ID=102>
<a id=”A1”>Today is a nice day2. 
<a id=”A2”>Today is a very nice day2.
<a id=”A3”>Today is a very very nice day2.
</B>
"""
invalid_tags = ['a',"html","body"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for tag in invalid_tags: 
    for match in soup.findAll(tag):
        match.replaceWithChildren()
print (soup)
```

This is because BeautifulSoup by default deals with html data.HTML is case insensitive; on parsing all tags are lowercased.

If you need to match tags case sensitive, you need to parse the document as XML. Install lxml(by pip) and tell BeautifulSoup to use that parser in XML mode
eg

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'xml')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the parent and child tags are just uppercase and lowercase versions. However, the uppercase (parent) version only contains numbers.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by that.Do you mean that the id of all upercase (parent) tags are numbers

Comment: You can make use of lambda functions + regex to  match id as per you pattern
eg:
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+")   
for match in soup.findAll( lambda tag:tag.name == "a" and  pattern.match(tag["id"])):

Comment: When I do that, I actually lose the content. Only these print: <a id="101">
</a>
<a id="102">
</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not correct.

See below fixed html + example code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<a id="101">
<a id="A1">Today is a nice day.</a>
<a id="A2">Today is a very nice day.</a>
<a id="A3">Today is a very very nice day.</a>
</a>

<a id="102">
<a id="A1">Today is a nice day2.</a>
<a id="A2">Today is a very nice day2.</a>
<a id="A3">Today is a very very nice day2.</a>
</a>
'''

bs = BeautifulSoup( html, "html.parser" )
tags = bs.find_all( "a", recursive = False )

for tag in tags:
    print( "<" + tag.name + ' id="' + tag[ "id" ] + '>' )
    print( tag.text )
    print( "</" + tag.name )
```

Comment: The original format of the file is correct. It's doesn't have the </a> closing tag for the child tags, only one closing tag for the parent tag. The parent tag ID contains only numbers.